# How can I make monthly backups (with dated file names) using Cron on Debian?

Tags: backup, cron, tar

I'm having trouble adding the date to the backup file's filename. Here's the Cron command (for testing):
`*/2 * * * tar -zcf /var/backups/www-(back tick)date +%Y%m%d(back tick).tgz /var/www/`

It should run every 2 minutes and create a backup file called www-20120212.tgz, but there's something wrong.

Comment: This is probably a typo, but you don't have enough fields at the start of your line. You probably want to put another * in before the tar command.

Answer (score 3):

'man crontab' says:

```
 The sixth field of a line in a crontab file is a string that
 is  executed  by the shell at the specified times. A percent
 character in this field (unless escaped by \) is  translated
 to a NEWLINE character
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `%` character with an `\`, as it will be interpreted differently by cron:

```
*/2 * * * tar -zcf /var/backups/www-`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.tgz /var/www/
```